# How to make rainwater clearer?

Tags: water, rain

I have collected rainwater but is a little greenish. Is there a way to make it more clean? Is the sun able to make it more cleaner?

Comment: why do you want it clearer? ... sun exposure will promote algae growth, so more green

Comment: Depends in part on the scale, end-use, and budget. "Sand filters" are a pretty common approach to removing bulk glop from rainwater. The sun, plus a black box with a sheet of glass and a trough can distill water, leaving most contaminants behind.

Comment: For a lot of the use cases of rain water, like feeding plants, the contaminants could be beneficial.  For human consumption.  Some of the most effective methods of purifying water, like distillation can actually purify it too much so it leeches needed minerals from the body, so it can require treatment before drinking in large quantity.  If you use water purification tablets, interestingly, you can also "safely" drink incredibly foul water.  Check out [The XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and try to be much more clear about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Add some fish they can eat the green stuff (aquaponics).